# I would like to understand how to get $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ From $[-\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\lambda x }]_0^\infty$

Tags: probability, integration

For calculating the mean of the exponential distribution we use the equation $\int_0^\infty 1- F(X)$. This gives $\int_0^\infty 1-1-e^{\lambda x}$ This leads to $[-\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\lambda x }]_0^\infty$. However, I would like to understand how this leads to a mean of the exponential distribution of $\frac{1}{\lambda}$? This question is from The Open University Unit 1 Probability and random variables.

Comment: My apologies for the incorrect title, that is supposed to be $\frac{1}{\lambda}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$\left[-\frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-\lambda x}\right]_0^\infty = \lim_{x \to \infty} -1/\lambda e^{- \lambda x} - (-1/\lambda e^{- \lambda 0}) = 0 + 1/\lambda = 1/\lambda$$